# Could a new AMD processor be limiting dd write speed when using /dev/urandom as the input?

Tags: devices, random

I have recently bought a new computer that uses a pretty recent AMD Athlon chip.
When using it for low-level formatting with `dd`, I noticed that setting `if=/dev/zero` allows it to write to the disk at the (possibly) highest speed that whatever disk I'm writing to allows, but whenever I set `if=/dev/urandom`, that speed is always stuck at 4.7MB/s, occassionally getting up to 4.8MB/s. This happens regardless of the distro I'm running it on (anything from the last three years up to more recent ones) or the disk I'm writing to (USB drives, SD cards, hard disks, etc).

From my experience, I've found that usually setting `bs=1024k` works that fastest with most disks so I use that.

What could be causing dd to be limited to this speed when running `dd` with `/dev/urandom` as an input and how do I go around it?

Comment: kernel version? urandom was very slow until kernel 4.8 or so

Comment: I've tried with different distros using different kernel versions. Anything from the 4.x kernels to the more recent 5.x kernels. I want to point out that these are live distros and that using them on other computers do not present the same problem and just on this new one, which makes me suspect it might be the processor.

Comment: It could be something else. To begin with I would get the disk out of the way (and everything between it and the process) by comparing on those machines for example `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1K count=1M` and `dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1K count=1M`. If the problem is still there, you can post more detailed info on one of the working processors and the AMD one (just AMD Athlon doesn't really tell a lot).